# CSS — ::selection with var() fallback

Tags: html, css, css-variables

I'm trying to change the selection color for an entire web page using a css variable:

```css
html {
  --my-var: red;
}

 ::selection {
  background-color: var(--my-var);
}
```

```html
<p>a b c</p>
<div>
  <p>x y z</p>
</div>
```

I correctly see the selection styling applied. However if `var` references a variable that is not defined, there is no selection color at all:

```
html {
  --my-var: red;
}

::selection {
  background-color: var(--not-my-var);
}
```

How can I define a selection color for an entire page that uses a css variable value if it is exists, or falls back to the default browser selection color? I've tried `var(--not-my-var, unset)`, `var(--not-my-var, inherit)` and `var(--not-my-var, initial)` but they do not seem to work

Comment: Wouldn't the issue lie more with how the CSS is setup if there is a `var` that isn't set? I'm curious of your use case where an unset variable could find it's way into your code that's not because of a typo.

Comment: The css variables are dynamically generated

Comment: How are the `vars` being generated? It seems that if the var is being dynamically generated and placed in the css, it would have a value assigned to it. Either way, the only way I've seen this worked around, is setting up the default property first, like `background-color: yellow (or whatever); background-color: var( --set-var)`. That way the second will override the first.

Comment: @disinfor Unfortunately this overriding also happens when --set-var is undefined, making the selection not noticeable.

Comment: @disinfor the good thing (or probably bad thing) with CSS variable is that at the end we will always have a value even if the CSS property is unset or having an invalid value. I am explaining this below.

Comment: @connexo ah right! I didn't realize that until I read Temani's answer that despite the variable not being set, it still renders as a valid value.

Comment: @TemaniAfif you provided some great information! I still wonder about the use case though in this situation - even if the variables are being dynamically generated - would the value assigned not also be set as well? I think that's my main struggle - I can't see how an unassigned variable would get into the CSS. I'm obviously missing something.

Comment: @disinfor the trick here is to understand the *computed* value. If you assign an invalid value for a property (ex: background:"bla bla") the browser is able to identify this at syntax level and will through it from the cascade and we no more consider this BUT if you use var(), the browser cannot know if yes or no this invalid so it be considered as valid value and will enter the cascade then later at computed time we may find it invalid and here we cannot go back, the browser should force it to be something valid by falling into initial or inherited value.

Comment: @TemaniAfif yeah, I get that passing an invalid value to a `var` will still make the browser compute something as valid although the value of the `var` may be invalid for that particular property (e.g. `background-color`). My concern is, why is an invalid value allowed to be assigned to that `var` in the first place? That seems like a programming issue. For example, why would `bla bla` be allowed to be assigned to `--my-background-color-var`, even if the vars are randomly generated.

Comment: @disinfor because a variable can be used everywhere with any property so technically it should accept all the possible values of all the properties which is *almost* anything. For example `"bla bla"` is a string and string is allowed as value for `content`. even spaces are allowed because you can do `--a:5px solid;` then `border:var(--a) red`.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Sure, I get that the variable can hold any value - but why would a `var` be assigned to a property if the value of that variable does not apply to that property? To use your example if there was a `--content-var: blah blah`, what would be the case that that var would end up being used in a property it shouldn't - like `border: var( --content-var )`?

Comment: @disinfor When saying `border: var( --content-var )` the browser don't know the content of the var until we do the cascading and we start computing. even if there is `:root{--content-var:"bla bla"}`. The content can only be known at computed time so at syntax level there is no way to know the content of a variable and the syntax is valid. probably we will have another CSS that will define the same variable with higher specificity. When it's invalid *at computed time* the browser will fall into initial but before computing we have a valid assignment.

Comment: @disinfor and the rules defines that at computed time if the variable contains an invalid value for that property then use initial and don't make the whole property invalid

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195704/discussion-between-disinfor-and-temani-afif).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to obtain what you want is to make sure the value is invalid so the browser will ignore it and fall back to the default one:

```css
::selection {
  background-color: something_invalid;
}
```

```html
<p>a b c</p>
<div>
  <p>x y z</p>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, this won't be possible when using `var(--variable)` since the value will never be invalid.

From [the specificatition](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/) we have the following steps to find the value:

> To substitute a var() in a property’s value:
>
> 1. If the custom property named by the first argument to the var() function is animation-tainted, and the var() function is being used in the animation property or one of its longhands, treat the custom property as having its initial value for the rest of this algorithm.
> 2. If the value of the custom property named by the first argument to the var() function is anything but the initial value, replace the var() function by the value of the corresponding custom property.
> 3. Otherwise, if the var() function has a fallback value as its second argument, replace the var() function by the fallback value. If there are any var() references in the fallback, substitute them as well.
> 4. Otherwise, the property containing the var() function is invalid at computed-value time.

(2) and (3) are trivial and will always give us a value. (1) tell us to treat the value of the custom property as `initial` and we will fall into (3) or (4).

For the (4) we can also read from the same specification:

> A declaration can be invalid at computed-value time if it contains a var() that references a custom property with **its initial value**, as explained above, or if it uses a valid custom property, but the property value, after substituting its var() functions, is **invalid**. When this happens, the computed value of the property is either **the property’s inherited** value or **its initial value** depending on whether the property is inherited or not, respectively, as if the property’s value had been specified as the unset keyword.

`background-color` is not inherited so it will use its initial value which is `transparent` that's why you see no color.

---

Now if we consider the fallback cases (3)

- using `initial` means the initial value of background color so transparent
- using `inherit` means inherit the color but there is nothing to inherit so transparent again
- using `unset` we will have a mix of `inherit` and `initial`

> The unset CSS keyword resets a property to its inherited value if it inherits from its parent, and to its initial value if not. In other words, it behaves like the inherit keyword in the first case, and like the initial keyword in the second case <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset)</sup>

---

Your only chance would probably be the use of [`revert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert) but the support is very low and I am not sure if it will work.

> The revert CSS keyword reverts the cascaded value of the property from its current value to the value the property would have had if no changes had been made by the current style origin to the current element. Thus, it resets the property to its inherited value if it inherits from its parent or **to the default value established by the user agent's stylesheet** (or by user styles, if any exist). <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert)</sup>

**Update**

As per the comments below, it seems also impossible with `revert`.

Comment: The current case is even worse than that, though I don't think it's worth an answer on its own and I didn't checked the specs, but the pseudo-class `::selection` that OP is trying to change is by default not even set by the UA stylesheet, but by the OS (at least in my macOs setup). So just setting one property of this pseudo-class will remove all the OS defaults (that is [`::selection{font-size:10px}`](https://jsfiddle.net/6vsrpg5m/) will both ignore the font-size which is not allowable, and discard the background color. This means that even in supporting browsers, `revert` won't work.

Comment: Here are the relevant specs: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-pseudo-4/#highlight-cascade "The UA should use the OS-default highlight colors for ::selection when neither color nor background-color has been specified by the author." and then the note saying that UAs can't even apply a "normal cascade" in the UA style sheet.

Comment: @Kaiido then the answer is a clear *no* but the font-size trick is a but surprising. I know that if you set color (or any allowed property) the background will reset to transparent (https://jsfiddle.net/d51L4kew/1/) but never though any property will do the same. This sounds like a bug.

Comment: Yes I got surprised too, but since there is no UA set `::selection` ruleset, I can only see how having an user-set one, be it invalidated, would overwrite the OS one (that the browser [doesn't/should pretend not to] know). And at least, this behavior is consistent in all of Chrome, Safari and Firefox on my macOs system.