# How can i export shorthand CSS properties (border, border-left, border-right...) as CSS variables

Tags: css, css-variables

If i do this:

```css
.a {
        border: var(--a-border);
        border-left: var(--a-border-left);
        border-right: var(--a-border-right);
        border-top: var(--a-border-top);
        border-bottom: var(--a-border-bottom);
}
```

Setting `--a-border` never works because individual properties like `a-border-left` have reset the value. What i'm thinking is that, i'm not giving any default values on those exported variables. Therefore, if `--a-border` is set, it should take precedence over other unset values.

Comment: this has nothing to do with CSS variable. The later property will always override the previous one.

Comment: *Therefore, if --a-border is set, it should take precedence over other unset values* --> even if you are not giving value to the CSS variables you are giving values to the property and this is enough even if the values are *empty* and will get computed to initial

Comment: I *guess* what you trying to do is set the general border style in `border` then edit the `border-color` or `border-width` in the following styles. if so - you have to override only the specific thing you want to change. i.e `border-right-color: green`, `border-left-width: 3px` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I explained in [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56799215/8620333) when using `border-left: var(--a-border-left)` it means that `border-left` will always have a valid value whataver the definition of the CSS variables. Considering this your shorthand property will always be ignored because the longhand ones will always override it.

One fix is to consider the fallback property and redefine the variable used inside the shorthand in each individual propery:

```css
.a {
  border: var(--a-border);
  border-left: var(--a-border-left,var(--a-border));
  border-right: var(--a-border-right,var(--a-border));
  border-top: var(--a-border-top,var(--a-border));
  border-bottom: var(--a-border-bottom,var(--a-border));
  
  
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  display:inline-block;
}

:root {
  --a-border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>

<div class="a" style="--a-border-bottom:5px solid green"></div>
```